# Python Selenium : Refresh HTML after AJAX call

Tags: python, ajax, selenium

I am using **Selenium 2.53.6** with **Python** to test form submission. When the form is posted, a confirmation mail is sent to : `first_name.last_name@mailinator.com`.

Selenium then navigates to the URL `https://www.mailinator.com/inbox2.jsp?public_to=first_name.last_name#/#public_maildirdiv` which is the inbox of the user identified by `first_name.last_name`.

When the page is loaded, it clicks on the div corresponding to the confirmation mail. This click creates an ajax request which loads the mail.

Now I want Selenium to click on the link to activate the email :
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='activationLink']").click()`

Problem is, due to the mail generated via AJAX, Selenium doesn't receive at anytime the HTML corresponding to the DOM generated after AJAX succeded.

In fact, **Selenium keeps the HTML of the inbox, but never achieves to get the mail HTML**.

**My question is:** Is it possible to refresh the HTML after AJAX call so Selenium can find the 
`<a id="activationLink">`?

**Note** : I already tried `WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "activationLink")))` 
or such tricks, but it won't change nothing since Selenium **doesn't refresh the HTML it is pointing to**

Comment: I think you misdiagnose the problem: generally selenium has no issue working with Ajax-based pages, and its knowledge about the page is based on DOM, not HTML source, so it is updated every time the page changes. So you have some other issue here. Maybe the link is in a frame?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I just found out the page was including an iframe, visible on a div click (an email), with a document within it. I went to look how I could do to select the document in the iframe, and found this : `driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_whatever(whatever))`. Thanks for your help!